# How to generate a list of random letters assigned to random numbers

Tags: python, random, integer, character

I need to create a list of random characters that are generated from random numbers. One list needs to be the letters generated from the random numbers, while the other list will get letters that are already in the first list. I have seen the import string method that uses the ascii, but I dont fully understand that. So far I have used the import random method and have been able to generate the random numbers but I feel my code is too long and that there should be an easier way.
Each time a random number is generated the program should convert it to a letter and add to a list (called
uniqueList) only if the number is not already present in the list. Stop adding the numbers once the list
contains 15 characters.

here is a sample of the code I have so far:

```
uniqueList = []
excludedList = []
count = 0


while (len(uniqueList)<15):

    randomNumber = random.randint(*random.choice([(65,90), (97,122)]))
    print(randomNumber)

    if(randomNumber == 65):
        letter = 'A'
    if(randomNumber == 66):
        letter = 'B'
    if(randomNumber == 67):
        letter = 'C'
    if(randomNumber == 68):
        letter = 'D'
    if(randomNumber == 69):
        letter = 'E'
    if(randomNumber == 70):
```

you can tell the code is long so i know there has to be a shorter way

Comment: `letter = chr(randomNumber)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need a random `letter`, you can simplify the logic by using [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) as:

```
import string
import random
my_char = string.letters
random.choice(my_char)
# returns 'z'
```

where `string.letters` will return string of all letters i.e. `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'`

---

Below is the modified code based on your logic of code (using `random.choice()` with random number) as:

```
import string
import random
my_char = string.letters
# Value returned by string.letters:
# 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

randomNumber = random.randint(*random.choice([(65,90), (97,122)]))
if randomNumber >=65 and randomNumber <=90:
   print my_char[randomNumber-65]
elif randomNumber >=97 and randomNumber <=122:
   print my_char[randomNumber-97+26]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want 15 unique letters in a list you could do the following:

```
import random
import string

letters = [i for i in string.ascii_lowercase]
random_list = random.sample(letters, 15)

print random_list
```

This would return something along the lines of:

```
['m', 's', 'r', 'f', 'x', 'l', 'e', 't', 'd', 'n', 'w', 'u', 'q', 'h', 'i']
```

Answer (score 0):

As c# knows the unicode values you can use

```
letter=(char)randomNumber;
```

although random a number between 97 and 122 as use did will random a lower case letter. If you want to random an uppercase letter like you quoted take a look in the unicode table for upper case unicode values.
http://unicode-table.com/en/